# Chrome extension: on document button click run browser_action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing and extention that will allow me to take a Screenshot of the entire page once clicked a certain button inside the page. 
The code is a slighty modified version of: https://github.com/mrcoles/full-page-screen-capture-chrome-extension

So if the user clicks on the extension icon it starts a capture. I need to be able to do the same by clicking a button inside the page, the button is already on the page. I added background.js and content.js and tried different approaches...without success. Do you know how to do it?

```
{
    "name": "", "version": "", 
    "manifest_version": 2, "description": "",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon48-999.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "matches": ["*://mydomain/app/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }]
}
```

Currently I'm able to listen to click events like this:

**content.js**

```
document.getElementById('top-nav').addEventListener('click', function () {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({screencapture: true});
});
```

**background.js**
...but I still get the "undefined" output...

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function () {
    alert('background.js');
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format: "png"}, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you'll have to show your UI as a normal DOM element inside the page (for example an iframe that points to a html page inside your extension).

Comment: I can listen to pages events trought content.js but i cant then make use chrome.tabs.executeScript

Comment: Then the question is incomplete/unclear. What is that button you want to click? Do you (want to) add it on all sites? If so, it can be done only using a content script which means the page will already have a content script and you don't need executeScript.

Comment: Yes, the element is alredy on the page.

Comment: Er, still too vague. Did you add the button on all pages using a content script? Or is it a specific site that has this button? For the latter you can use [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) but only if the site is HTTPS. Anyway, we can't read each other's minds so please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry man :D Yes the website is on https and it has the button by default. I just managed to use chrome.runtime.sendMessage() and chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener() to do some communication

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for helping! Do you know if there is a way to simulate the browser bar extension click?

Comment: It's chrome.browserAction.showPopup but it doesn't work in the standard Chrome so no, there's no way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173156/discussion-between-karc-and-woxxom).